# Python type hint for objects that have "@" (matrix-multiply)

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a function `fun()` that accepts a NumPy [ArrayLike](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html) and a "matrix", and returns a numpy array.

```py
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike
import numpy as np

def fun(A, x: ArrayLike) -> np.ndarray:
    return (A @ x) ** 2 - 27.0
```

What's the correct `type` for entities that have an `@` operation? Note that `fun()` could also accept a [scipy.sparse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html); perhaps more.

Comment: AFIK, numpy.typing has not been extended to cover scipy.sparse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `typing.Protocol` to assert that the type implements `__matmul__`.

```
class SupportsMatrixMultiplication(typing.Protocol):
    def __matmul__(self, x):
        ...


def fun(A: SupportsMatrixMultiplication, x: ArrayLike) -> np.ndarray:
    return (A @ x) ** 2 - 27.0
```

You can, I believe, further refine this by providing type hints for `x` and a return type hint, if you want more than just supporting `@` as an operator.

Comment: for readers, [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) is python 3.8+. it is also available in the `typing_extensions` package